# Schedule python script to run within the script

Tags: python, cron

I have created a Mac based notification script using python. However, I want the script to run at a certain time and date.

So the user enters the time and date and the program runs the script then and does the Desktop notification.

I am just unsure of how to control crontab -e from within Python3.

For example, I add a notification and set it to run at 1:30pm.

crontab-e should be:

```
*/1:30pm * * * * /usr/bin/python3 script.py
```

If anyone knows how to do this, please help. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Is `python 3` a typo, or should it be `python3` (no space in).

Comment: this was a typo @vahdet

Comment: 34 13 * * * /usr/bin/python3 script.py, try to check this to test out the possible crontab schedule. https://crontab.guru/

Comment: yes but I need the python script to automatically add that script into crontab -e @vpdiongzon

Comment: At least under Linux, the crontab syntax for 1.30pm is `30 13 * * * <command>`. I'd be surprised if Mac isn't the same, though I don't have access to one to test it.

Comment: Also on Linux, the `crontab` implementation lets you do `crontab -` to read the crontab information from standard input. So you would typically capture the output of `crontab -l`, manipulate it as you wish and then feed it to `crontab -` to write it back again. (No interactive editor involved.) Again, I am guessing (untested) that it will be similar on a Mac.

Comment: There is also this package, although not in the standard library: https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/

Comment: yes I am aware of python-crontab, I am just unsure how to use it to schedule an event from within the script @alaniwi